# null-coalescing operator on a property get

Tags: c#

So, I am [reading an article at the moment](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) and I came across some code which has caused me to question it.

The code looks like this:

```
private UserService _userService = null;

protected UserService UserService
{
    get { return _userService ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); }
}
```

To me, it looks like the private property will always be null, so using the null-coalescing operator is useless.
I would imagine it is as useful as doing this:

```
protected UserService UserService
{
    get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); }
}
```

Am I missing something? And while we are on the subject, why do this:

```
private UserService _userService = null;
```

surely that is the same as

```
private UserService _userService;
```

Please help me clarify my suspicions :D

Comment: It's a common pattern to write `get { return _userService ?? _userService  = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); }`. Perhaps it was a typo?

Comment: Perhaps the idea is  to let user set `_userService` in code somewhere and if he did return that value, if he didn't just get it from Identity. It is also a possibility that `GetUserManager<UserService>()`  returns same object per context, the service instance is always the same and there is no special reasons to store it in a field.

Comment: if there is no reason to store it, wouldn't my proposed solution (just returning it from the context) be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add my two cents here :

One possible reason is that developer(s) wanted to create `readonly` property that uses value of `_userService` field if it was assigned by user (di container) only and if it wasn't simply return value from `Identity` value provider (most likely this provider uses singleton per http context).

Generally speaking, i kind of dislike the idea of assigning field's value inside of `getter` method of a property since `setter` exists for this sole purpose.

Provided that we'd like to change something in code to make it more 'in a normal way' we could set this field in a constructor and add optional parameter to it :

```
private UserService _userService;

protected UserService UserService
{
    get
    {
        return _userService;
    }
}

public MyController(UserService service = null)
{
   this._userService = service ?? 
          Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>();
}
```

Now code is more testable and neat. It also allows us to use DI frameworks. The only drawback of this approach is that we moved away from lazy loading. Well, we could use it again with `Lazy<T>` :

```
private Lazy<UserService> _userService;

protected UserService UserService
{
    get
    {
        return _userService.Value;
    }
}

public MyController(UserService service = null)
{
     service = service ?? 
          Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>();

     _userService = new Lazy<UserService>(service);
}
```

Now it is easier to unit test our code, we can use DI framework and benefit from using of  lazy loading.

P.S.

Assign of `null` value explicitly to field of reference type doesn't make much sense to me. The only reason i could think of is that it slightly improve readability but this seem to be entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, the private property will always be null in your example.

One way to solve it, is using this code:

```
private UserService _userService = null;

protected UserService UserService
{
    get
    {
        return _userService ?? (_userService = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>());
    }
}
```

This way the private property is used when not null, or is initialized to the assigned value. When the statement after the null-coalescing operator `??` is executed, the assigned value to `_userService` is actually returned by the propery.

Comment: @CarbineCoder What error message are you getting? This should actually compile, because the statement after the '??' returns the _userService.

Comment: @CarbineCoder Everything is correct here. Assigning operation returns assigned value in C# (maybe this behavior is different in some languages).

Comment: my bad... Sorry I missed the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon to have that approach, but usually it comes with a parameterized constructor like:

```
public class X
{
   private UserService _userService = null;

   protected UserService UserService
   {
       get { return _userService ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); }
   }


   public X() { }

   public X(UserService svc) { _userService = svc; }
```

Or some other way of populating the service method, like a method:

```
public void SetUserService(UserService svc) { _userSErvice = svc; }
```

The benefit to doing that you can construct with with a mocked UserService service using a mocking framework like Moq or Rhino.Mocks.

Comment: but if you don't have a parameterized constructor it's useless right?

Comment: Yeah or as @Herman says that solution works, or do that solution in the constructor (initialize the variable there).

Answer (score 0):

As @Rob mentioned in the comments it's a normal pattern doing

```
get { return _userService ?? _userService = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); }
```

C# 8 added the [null-coalescing assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) which adds a little syntactic sugar to this pattern:

```
get { return _userService ??= Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); }
```

This accomplishes the same as `_userService ?? _userService =`.